# Count System Events using CMD loop, PSLOGFILE and input file

Tags: loops, cmd

I need to count system Events on group of servers (servers.txt) within some X days range. Can someone help me modify this loop to add servername and the count in the result file?

I need something like:

```
server1 368 SystemEvents within last 2 days
server2 555434 SystemEvents within last 2 days
server3 2 SystemEvents within last 2 days
```

I know I'm pretty close:)

```
for /f "eol=" %%i IN (servers.txt) DO psloglist \\%%i -d 2 system | find /c "[" >> result.txt
```

I know psloglist can use @servers.txt parametr, but there is no way to add server names in the result file.

Answer (score 0):

This echoes text like `server1 368 SystemEvents within last 2 days`

It uses an extra loop to capture the count, and so you can echo the information that you need.

```
@echo off
(
   for /f "delims=" %%a in (servers.txt) do (
      echo checking server %%a
        for /f "delims=" %%b in ('psloglist \\%%a -d 2 system ^| find /c "[" ') do echo %%a %%b SystemEvents within last 2 days
   )
)>result.txt
pause
```